# Unable to submit Topology using streamParse "thriftpy.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing beginFileUpload"

Tags: python, apache-storm

I am trying to submit a topology to an remote ubuntu machine using

`sparse submit` command

and getting the following error

```
  File "...../bin/sparse", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('streamparse==4.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'sparse')()
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamparse-4.0.0-py3.6.egg/streamparse/cli/sparse.py", line 85, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "../lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamparse-4.0.0-py3.6.egg/streamparse/cli/submit.py", line 391, in main
    active=args.active,
  File "../lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamparse-4.0.0-py3.6.egg/streamparse/cli/submit.py", line 295, in submit_topology
    remote_jar_path = _upload_jar(nimbus_client, local_jar_path)
  File "../lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamparse-4.0.0-py3.6.egg/streamparse/cli/submit.py", line 158, in _upload_jar
    upload_location = nimbus_client.beginFileUpload()
  File "../lib/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy-0.3.9-py3.6-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 198, in _req
    return self._recv(_api)
  File "../lib/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy-0.3.9-py3.6-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 215, in _recv
    raise x
thriftpy.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing beginFileUpload
```

I have also tried giving the root access to the storm installed in the remote machine

Here is my config

```
{
    "serializer": "json",
    "topology_specs": "topologies/",
    "virtualenv_specs": "virtualenvs/",
    "envs": {
        "prod": {
            "user": "abc",
            "ssh_password": "abc",
            "nimbus": "ip.ip.ip.ip",
            "workers": ["ip.ip.ip.ip"],
            "log": {
                "path": "",
                "max_bytes": 1000000,
                "backup_count": 10,
                "level": "debug"
            },
            "options": {
                "virtualenv_flags": "-p /usr/bin/python3.6",
                "supervisor.worker.timeout.secs" : 1800

            },
            "virtualenv_root": "/home/abc/virtualenvs",
            "use_ssh_for_nimbus": true

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue over here was the ip to which topology was getting submitted was a non leader supervisor. The storm accepts topology submission only on Leader Supervisor node

Comment: leader is not a supervisor

Comment: Among all the supervisors, the one is elected as leader and the submission of topology must be to that node, streamparse internally doesn't identify that